# Compact operator in $L^2$ theory of linear elliptic equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

If
$$
A: L^2(\Omega) \rightarrow H_0^1(\Omega)
$$
is a bounded linear operator, and
$$
E:H_0^1(\Omega) \rightarrow  L^2(\Omega)
$$
is compact imbedding,  then how to show
$$
A=AE: H_0^1(\Omega) \rightarrow  H_0^1(\Omega)
$$
is compact ?

This question is gotten when I read a book about PDE,  I fail to get why $A=AE$ is compact.  And, in fact, I don't know  what is the mean of $A=AE$.

Comment: you know the definition of a compact operator, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compact operator is one which sends bounded sets to relatively compact sets. If $X\subset H_0^1(\Omega)$ is bounded and $E$ is a compact operator, then $E(X)$ is compact in $L^2(\Omega)$. Since $A$ is bounded, it sends relatively compact sets to relatively compact sets, meaning that $A(E(X))$ is compact in $H_0^1(\Omega)$. You can also do it through sequences, if you'd like.

In general, if $T:V\rightarrow W$ is compact, $S_1:V_1\rightarrow V$ is bounded, and $S_2:W\rightarrow W_2$ is bounded, then $S_2TS_1:V_1\rightarrow W_2$ is compact, via the same reasoning.

Comment: If $A$ is bounded, it send compact sets to compact sets.   By this way, I think  it is easy to understand than relatively compact, is it ?

Comment: Sure. Technically, the image of a compact space under a continuous function is relatively compact in the codomain. Since we're talking about a subset of a space, everything should really be phrased in terms of relative compactness. Again, it's a technicality, and people often drop the "relative" phrase.